# commutative rings over which any module $M$ satisfies $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Can we classify those commutative rings $R$ such that $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann}M)$ for every module $M$ over $R$ ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_of_a_module)

[NOTE: For a subset $S$ of a commutative ring $R$ with unity, $V(S):=\{\mathfrak p : \mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and $S \subseteq \mathfrak p\}$ ]

(We know that if $M$ is a finitely generated module over a commutative ring with unity $R$ then $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$. Is it true that over every commutative ring $R$, there is a module $M$ such that $\operatorname{Supp}(M)\ne V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$ ?)

Comment: If $R$ is local and the maximal ideal is its only prime, then every non-zero module satisfies your requirement, so the answer to your last question is negative.

Comment: @user26857: Ah true, a zero dimensional local ring ... and anything in the converse direction ?

Comment: If $R$ is local with $\dim R=1$, and $\bigcap_{k\ge 1}m^k=(0)$ (e.g., $R$ is Noetherian), then set $M=\bigoplus_{k\ge 1}R/m^k$. In this case $\operatorname{Supp}(M)\ne V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$. (Not a characterization, but this shows a different behavior for $\dim R>0$.)

Comment: @user26857: I'm having difficulty determining what is Supp$(M)$ and $Ann M$ in your second example

Comment: @user26857: I can see that $Ann M=0$, but what is Supp$(M)$ ... certainly $\mathfrak m \in $Supp $(M)$,  is it a proper subset of $Spec (R)$ ?

Comment: Supp(M) = {m}...

Comment: Titles should be informative and should help people searching quickly determine whether the question is relevant to what they are looking for. There's no reason to edit a post weeks later to remove information from its title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true of a ring $R$ iff $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a finite discrete space (or equivalently, the quotient of $R$ by its nilradical is a finite product of fields).

First, suppose $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$ for every $R$-module $M$.  We will first prove that every prime ideal in $R$ is maximal.  Suppose $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ is prime but not maximal.  Let $S=R/\mathfrak{p}$; then $S$ is a domain but not a field.  Let $a\in S$ be a nonzero element which is not a unit, and consider the $R$-module $M=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S/(a^n)$.  Let $I=\bigcap_n (a^n)\subset S$ and let $J$ be the inverse image of $I$ in $R$.  It is clear that $I$ is the annihilator of $M$ as an $S$-module, so $J$ is the annihilator of $M$ as an $R$-module.

On the other hand, $I$ generates a proper ideal in the localization $S[a^{-1}]$.  Indeed, since $a$ is not a zero divisor, the only way $I$ could fail to generate a proper ideal is if $a^n\in I$ for some $n$, which would imply $a^n\in (a^{n+1})$ so $a^n=a^{n+1}b$ for some $b\in S$.  Again since $a$ is not a zero divisor, this implies $1=ab$ so $a$ is a unit, contrary to our choice of $a$.

Thus $I$ generates a proper ideal in $S[a^{-1}]$, and we can extend it to a maximal ideal.  This maximal ideal pulls back to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset R$ such that $J\subseteq\mathfrak{q}$ but $\bar{a}\not\in\mathfrak{q}$ where $\bar{a}\in R$ is an element whose image in $S$ is $a$.  Since every element of $M$ is annihilated by some power of $\bar{a}$, $M_\mathfrak{q}=0$, so $\mathfrak{q}\not\in \operatorname{Supp}(M)$.  But since $J\subseteq \mathfrak{q}$, $\mathfrak{q}\in V(J) =V(\operatorname{Ann M})$.  This contradicts our assumption that $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$ for all $R$-modules $M$.

Thus every prime in $R$ is maximal.  Now if $\mathfrak{p}$ is any maximal ideal, the module $R/\mathfrak{p}$ has support $\{\mathfrak{p}\}$.  Thus for any subset $A\subseteq\operatorname{Spec} R$, the module $M=\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in A}R/\mathfrak{p}$ has support $A$.  Since $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann M})$ and $V(I)$ is a closed set for any ideal $I$, this implies every subset of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is closed, so $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is discrete.  Finally, since $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is quasicompact, this implies it is also finite.

---

Conversely, suppose $R$ is a ring such that $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a finite discrete space.  Then $R$ can be identified with the finite product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}}R_\mathfrak{p}$ of its localizations at all its prime ideals.  When we make this identification, each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ corresponds to the elements of $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}}R_\mathfrak{p}$ whose $\mathfrak{p}$-coordinate is in the unique maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak{p}$.  Also, any $R$-module $M$ is naturally isomorphic to the direct sum $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}}M_\mathfrak{p}$ of its localizations at all the prime ideals.  The annihilator of $M$ is then the product $\prod_\mathfrak{p} \operatorname{Ann}_{R_\mathfrak{p}} M_\mathfrak{p}\subseteq\prod_{\mathfrak{p}}R_\mathfrak{p}$.  Thus $\operatorname{Ann} M\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ iff $\operatorname{Ann}_{R_\mathfrak{p}} M_\mathfrak{p}$ is contained in the unique maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak{p}$.  Since any proper ideal in $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is contained in the unique maximal ideal, this means $\operatorname{Ann} M\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ iff $M_\mathfrak{p}\neq 0$.  That is, $\mathfrak{p}\in V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$ iff $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Supp}(M)$, so $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$.

Comment: How can you identify $R$ as the product at its localizations ? What is the isomorphism .?

Comment: Just take the canonical map from $R$ to the product of its localizations.  That map is an isomorphism by the sheaf property of the structure sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec} R$, using the open cover consisting of all the singletons.

Comment: Okay ... unfortunately I don't know anything about sheaf ... can you point out any easy way to see that the canonical map is injective ?

Comment: I don't think there's any particularly simple proof.  If you assume $R$ is reduced, then the intersection of all the prime ideals is $0$, so the Chinese remainder theorem gives an isomorphism $R\cong\prod_\mathfrak{p}R/\mathfrak{p}$, and then you can show $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is actually the same as $R_\mathfrak{p}$ (this is easy by direct computation in the ring $\prod_\mathfrak{p}R/\mathfrak{p}$ which is a product of fields).  But the argument is messier if $R$ is not reduced.

Comment: Um I see ... can you give any reference where that direct product identification of rings and modules is given ... any wriiten down proof that is ? It would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a reference.  This is all a corollary of basic scheme theory, so you can find all the prerequisites in any book that covers schemes from scratch (e.g., chapter II of Hartshorne's _Algebraic Geometry_).  But I don't think I've seen these specific facts written down explicitly.  Once you have the product expression for $R$, the statement for modules follows easily, just by analyzing what a module over a product of rings can look like (a module over $R\times S$ has the form $M\times N$ where $M$ is an $R$-module and $N$ is an $S$-module).

Comment: Here's a sketch of an argument you can give even if $R$ is not reduced.  Let $I(\mathfrak{p})$ be the kernel of the natural map $R\to R_\mathfrak{p}$.  You can show that $\sqrt{I(\mathfrak{p})}=\mathfrak{p}$ (this is essentially the statement that every element of the maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is nilpotent, since it is the only prime ideal).  This implies $I(\mathfrak{p})+I(\mathfrak{q})=R$ if $\mathfrak{p}\neq\mathfrak{q}$.  Also, $\bigcap_\mathfrak{p}I(\mathfrak{p})=0$, so the Chinese remainder theorem gives an isomorphism $R\cong \prod_\mathfrak{p}R/I(\mathfrak{p})$.

Comment: Now by just counting the number of prime ideals in $\prod_\mathfrak{p}R/I(\mathfrak{p})$ you can conlcude that $R/I(\mathfrak{p})$ has only one prime ideal for each $\mathfrak{p}$, which implies actually $R/I(\mathfrak{p})$ is equal to the localization $R_\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Okay ... I can see that $R/I(\mathfrak p)$ is local and is isomorphic to a subring of $R_{\mathfrak p} $ ... but why is that subring exactly $R_{\mathfrak p} $ ?

Comment: Well, $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is obtained from $R/I(\mathfrak{p})$ by adjoining inverses to every element of $R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$.  But the image of $\mathfrak{p}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R/I(\mathfrak{p})$, so all those elements already have inverses in $R/I(\mathfrak{p})$.

Comment: Thanks , I got that ... is there a similar elementary argument for the identification of module with its direct sum of localisations ?

Comment: Let $e_\mathfrak{p}$ be the element of $\prod_\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$ whose $\mathfrak{p}$ coordinate is $1$ and all other coordinates are $0$.  You can then verify that any module $M$ is the direct sum of the submodules $e_\mathfrak{p}M$, and that $e_\mathfrak{p}M$ can be identified with the localization $M_\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your proof of zero-dimensionality of $R$ only requires that countably generated modules $M$ has the property $V(Ann (M))= Supp (M)$ , right ? Only for proving the discrereness of spectrum, you have used larger modules. Do you think that over zero-dimensional rings, countably generated modules satisfy $V(Ann (M))= Supp (M)$  ?

Comment: The proof of discreteness also only needs countably generated modules.  It shows that any countable subset of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is closed, and thus discrete (since every subset of it is also closed).  But a closed subset must be quasicompact, and a countably infinite discrete space is not quasicompact.  So there cannot exist any countably infinite subset, and so $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is finite.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot. Do you think anything can be said about $R$ if we only assume that the support of every (/countably generated) $R$-module is Zariski-closed set ?

Comment: Well, the possible supports of modules are exactly the specialization-closed sets, so this is equivalent to saying that every specialization-closed set is closed.  That imposes some major restrictions (for instance, there must be only finitely many maximal ideals, and there can be no infinite descending chain of prime ideals) but I don't know any simpler description than that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the posets that can be the poset of prime ideals of such a ring can be characterized as follows: they are the well-founded posets $P$ with the property that for any finite subset $A\subseteq P$, there is a finite subset $B\subseteq P$ such that for any $p\in P$, $p\leq a$ for all $a\in A$ iff $p\leq b$ for some $b\in B$.  (You can think of this as sort of saying that $P$ has finite meets up to a "finite ambiguity".)

Comment: In particular, for instance, such $P$ include any finite poset or any well-ordered set.  It also includes things like a poset with one maximal element and infinitely many incomparable elements below it.

Comment: You have proved : let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. If for every countably generated $R$-module $M$, $V(Ann M)= Supp M$, then $Spec (R)$ is finite, discrete. And if $Spec(R)$ is finite ,discrete, then $V(Ann M)=Supp M$ for every $R$-module $M$. Is there a Scheme theoretic generalization of this ? If there is, could you please add that to your answer ?

Comment: This answer has been mostly copied to an arxiv paper, without acknowledgement. See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3798/deleted-answered-question?noredirect=1#comment16652_3798