# On the support of sheaf of modules or quasi-coherent sheaves over ringed spaces

Tags: commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

This question [Characterize commutative rings over which any module $M$ satisfies $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589180/characterize-commutative-rings-over-which-any-module-m-satisfies-operatornam) asks to characterize commutative rings over which support of modules are of special form. Is there an analog of that question and answer to the case of sheaf of modules or quasi-coherent sheaves over general ringed-spaces or schemes ?